# Sequelize: Category Model hierarchical structure with self reference

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

My MySQL database contains a Category Table (Maybe the "parent" column is the wrong approach here):

```
+----+--------------+--------+
| id |     name     | parent |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | Service      | null   |
|  2 | Lifestyle    | null   |
|  3 | Food & Drink | 2      |
|  4 | Beauty       | 2      |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

How is it possible to structure and retrieve the data with Sequelize in the following form:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Service",
        "children": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Lifestyle",
        "children": [
                      {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Food & Drink",
                        "children": null
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Beauty",
                        "children": null
                      },
                    ]
    }
]
```

I am using Sequelize cli. This is what I tried:

To Query Categories:

```
    const result = await models.Category.findAll({
        where: {
          parent: null
        },
        include: ['Category']
      });
    res.send(result);
```

My Category Model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Category = sequelize.define(
    'Category',
    {
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      parent: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
    },
    {}
  );
  Category.associate = function(models) {
    models.Category.belongsTo(models.Category, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: 'parent'
    });
  };
  return Category;
};
```

Results in the following error:

> "Not unique table/alias: 'Category'"

Whats the right solution to structure my Categories? Use children instead of parent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add in Category Model:

```
as: 'children'
```

and change

```
belongsTo
```

to

```
hasMany
```

like:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Category = sequelize.define(
    'Category',
    {
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      parent: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
    },
    {}
  );
  Category.associate = function(models) {
    models.Category.hasMany(models.Category, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: 'parent',
      as: 'children'
    });
  };
  return Category;
};
```

Your Query Categories now looks like:

```
const result = await models.Category.findAll({
    where: {
      parent: null
    },
    include: [{
      model: models.Category,
      as: 'children'
    }]
  });
res.send(result);
```

Comment: Is there a way to add in the columns if the element is a leaf or not? Thx